# Why do we need the unset here?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Given the following example: (from Zend Quick Start Tutorial btw)

```
public function save(Application_Model_Guestbook $guestbook)
{
  $data = array(
    'email'   => $guestbook->getEmail(),
    'comment' => $guestbook->getComment(),
    'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  );

  if (null === ($id = $guestbook->getId())) {
     unset($data['id']);
     $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
  } else {
     $this->getDbTable()->update($data, array('id = ?' => $id));
  }
}
```

Why do we need the unset there ?
I mean, why do we need to destroy a specific array key, if we haven't declare it before ?
And even more bizarre, where do we declare it anyway?

We can have a look on getDbTable method, but even looking at it, I don't find an answer:

```
public function getDbTable()
{
    if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
        $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook');
    }
    return $this->_dbTable;
}
```

And if we look into the setDbTable method, there's no $data anywhere.

```
public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }
```

I know that Zend Framework will automatically find the id of our table here:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /** Table name */
    protected $_name    = 'guestbook';
}
```

But I don't understand if this is related somehow...

I believe I've put all the relevant information. Still, if there's nothing relevant, perhaps I'm missing something here:
(source)
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

Thanks a lot

Comment: You only need the unset in there if the $data array has an id coming from anywhere else which doesnt seem to be the case but since you are showing just a bit of the code we can say for sure. If the $data has an id set somewhere else.

Comment: Updated my question with the reference link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems to imply that `$data['id']` is always set, but it might have an empty value (`''` or `'0'`). The `unset` is there to prevent the `INSERT` SQL query from trying to insert every new record with a fixed id of `0` (or to prevent the query from breaking due to invalid SQL syntax, can't tell with just this information) in this case.

**Update:** After reading it once more, it's obvious that the array `$data` *cannot* have its `id` member set at all (there's no code that might set it). Therefore that line is completely redundant the way the code is written right now. It might be a leftover from a previous version of the code.

Comment: Thanks. At least now I understand the need for it. I'm still not understanding where does it come from. I will update my question to add getDbTable and setDbTable methods, perhaps it will help.

Comment: I've added even more information. I just want to make sure because, this is Zend Official Documentation and I really doubt my skills, so, perhaps I'm missing something obvious, or even if not obvious, something that Zend do, and I'm not aware. :s - Just need a confirmation to move on. :)

Comment: @MEM: No, you are not missing something obvious. `$data` is set locally and cannot be modified by any code outside this function. No way it can have an `id` key as the code stands.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `id` is an autoincrement field. The `unset` is used to make sure, that the INSERT statement will not use a random id, but `null`.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Now I know that we can use unset for that propose. :)